# Delete all zip files from a folder recursivley

Tags: bash, command-line, find, delete

I am trying to delete all zip files from a folder `/mnt/drive1/temp` and its subfolders recursivley.

I am aware that an incorrect command here could have disastrous consequences so wanted to check I had the right format, so far I have...

```
find /mnt/drive/temp -type f -name '*.zip' -delete
```

Will this command achieve what I want?

Comment: use *-iname* to delete all ZIP files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you omit the `-delete` option, `find` will print out a list of all files that match the test conditions you have specified. This is great way to check that you have caught the right files, especially before you delete them. Once you're sure that the files are the right ones, append the `-delete` option and run the command.

---

Syntactically, your command appears correct, but there may be a typo. You have `find` followed by the path ('/mnt/drive/temp'). You have also mentioned '/mnt/drive1/temp' in the question, which is a different path. This is the possible typo I am referring.

Followed by the path, you have a series of tests. `-type f` will find regular files, and `-name '*.zip'` will find files that end with the .zip extension. The single quotes prevent the shell from expanding the '*' character, which is the correct approach.

As stated above, first do a 'dry run' without the `-delete` option. Then, review the output and confirm that the files are correct. Once you are satisfied, proceed to delete the files.